# How to return Scanner.in value from the method to another method

Tags: java, return

I want to make some simple program which will count monthly rate of product. There is two inputs: cost of the product - between 100-10000 and number of rates - between 6-48. I wanted to do it like in the code below:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
double productCost;
int numberOfRates;
double loanInterestRate;
double monthlyRate;

Double print () {
Calculator c = new Calculator();
System.out.println ("Enter the value of your product from 100 to 10 000 : ");
productCost=sc.nextDouble();
if (productCost < 100){
    System.out.println ("You have to choose price between 100 to 10000. Try again: ");
    c.print();
} else if (productCost >10000){
    System.out.println ("You have to choose price between 100 to 10000. Try again: ");
    c.print();
} else if (productCost >= 100 || productCost <=10000){

    c.print1();
    return = productCost;
   // how to return productCost to be used in next method print1()?
}
else return null;   

}
void print1(){
Calculator c = new Calculator(); 
System.out.println ("Now enter how many rates do you want to pay from 6 to 48: ");
numberOfRates=sc.nextInt();
if (numberOfRates<6){
    System.out.println ("You can't choose this number of rates. Choose between 6-48: ");
    c.print1();
} else if (numberOfRates>48){
    System.out.println ("You can't choose this number of rates. Choose between 6-48: ");
    c.print1();
} else if (numberOfRates>=6 || numberOfRates<=12) {
    loanInterestRate=1.025;
    monthlyRate = (productCost*loanInterestRate)/numberOfRates;
    System.out.printf("Your monthly rate is: "+ "%.2f%n",monthlyRate);
} else if (numberOfRates>=13 || numberOfRates <=24 ) {
    loanInterestRate=1.05;
    monthlyRate = (productCost*loanInterestRate)/numberOfRates;
    System.out.printf("Your monthly rate is: "+ "%.2f%n",monthlyRate);
} else if (numberOfRates >=25|| numberOfRates<=48){
    loanInterestRate=1.1;
    monthlyRate = (productCost*loanInterestRate)/numberOfRates;
    System.out.printf("Your monthly rate is: "+ "%.2f%n",monthlyRate);
}
}
}
```

And the main method only calling the method from the other class.

```
public class MonthlyRate {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calc = new Calculator();
    calc.print();
    // TODO code application logic here
}

}
```

And what is the problem, I don't know how to return the "double productCost" from the method "print()". productCost is taking from the input and this is double but NetBeans showing me that it's not correct type. Can anybody help me understand where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do

```
    return productCost;
```

`return` is a keyword, not a variable. It 'returns' the given value and exits the function, so that the entity calling the function can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    double cost = calc.print();  // note calc.print() PRODUCES a value, which we assign to `cost`
    ...
}
```

You can then do whatever you want with `cost` (or whatever you choose to name the variable), including passing it to another function.

Answer (score 1):

Your program needs changes in a few places. I have done those changes and written below the updated program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Calculator {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double productCost;
    int numberOfRates;
    double loanInterestRate;
    double monthlyRate;

    void print() {
        Calculator c = new Calculator();
        System.out.println("Enter the value of your product from 100 to 10 000 : ");
        productCost = sc.nextDouble();
        if (productCost < 100) {
            System.out.println("You have to choose price between 100 to 10000. Try again: ");
            c.print();
        } else if (productCost > 10000) {
            System.out.println("You have to choose price between 100 to 10000. Try again: ");
            c.print();
        } else if (productCost >= 100 || productCost <= 10000) {
            print1(productCost);            
        }
    }

    void print1(double productCost) {
        Calculator c = new Calculator();
        System.out.println("Now enter how many rates do you want to pay from 6 to 48: ");
        numberOfRates = sc.nextInt();
        if (numberOfRates < 6) {
            System.out.println("You can't choose this number of rates. Choose between 6-48: ");
            c.print1(productCost);
        } else if (numberOfRates > 48) {
            System.out.println("You can't choose this number of rates. Choose between 6-48: ");
            c.print1(productCost);
        } else if (numberOfRates >= 6 || numberOfRates <= 12) {
            loanInterestRate = 1.025;
            monthlyRate = (productCost * loanInterestRate) / numberOfRates;
            System.out.printf("Your monthly rate is: " + "%.2f%n", monthlyRate);
        } else if (numberOfRates >= 13 || numberOfRates <= 24) {
            loanInterestRate = 1.05;
            monthlyRate = (productCost * loanInterestRate) / numberOfRates;
            System.out.printf("Your monthly rate is: " + "%.2f%n", monthlyRate);
        } else if (numberOfRates >= 25 || numberOfRates <= 48) {
            loanInterestRate = 1.1;
            monthlyRate = (productCost * loanInterestRate) / numberOfRates;
            System.out.printf("Your monthly rate is: " + "%.2f%n", monthlyRate);
        }
    }
}

public class MonthlyRate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calculator calc = new Calculator();
        calc.print();
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

It is easy to understand the changes after comparing your program with this updated program. Nevertheless, feel free to let me know if you need any further help on this.

Comment: Thanks ! i got it ;)